# Sortable vs draggable jQuery and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

Thanks for reading.

My rails webpage has a number of buttons and links. These are sorted nicely according to div class. When I use jQuery's draggable function, I can isolate one submission link, and drag it. The buttons, link, etc, all stay together as one unit. Perfect!

If I change the word "draggable" to "sortable" to get the effect I really want, then the functionality that my divs were providing changes. The components of one post are no longer bound together. The upvote button is not attached to the link, is not attached to the downvote button, etc.

I will provide images and code to help explain. I appreciate any advice. Thank you.

*The post components drag as a single unit*
[image: draggable]

*The post components sort individually within their own post. Border added to make clear what's happening. The goal is, of course, to sort entire posts, not just components, moving them above or below each other.*

[image]

```
<script src="/javascripts/jQueryUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(function () {
$(".individual_link").sortable();
});
</script>


<div class="summary_title">
<th>Page Title.</th><br><br>
</div>

<div class="all_submission_links">
<% @submissions.each do |submission| %>

    <div class="individual_link">
    <%= link_to submission.summary, submission, :id =>       "individual_link" %>

  <% #Had to use try method because if email is nil (user delted   account) program will crash. %>
  <div class="submission_dates"><p>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(submission.created_at) %> ago by <%= submission.user.try(:username) %></p>
  </div>
   <%= link_to like_submission_path(submission), method: :put, class:   "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    Upvote
    <%= submission.get_upvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to dislike_submission_path(submission), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
    Downvote
    <%= submission.get_downvotes.size %></span>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This sorting process is made difficult because I am using a ruby method instead of the typical unordered list method. I would appreciate any advice on how to sort posts in their entirety as seen in this example: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the difference between draggable and sortable in this context. To make it work as sortable, all I had to do was make the all_submission_links class sortable, instead of the individual_link class.

Hopefully this helps someone out in the future who is working with draggable and sortable.